# Expression in SSIS - Derived column to change the Date from the last SIX days

Tags: datetime, ssis

I am working on SSIS and my question is I am having an XML file data in that data one column header is **TIMESTAMP** and the **TIMESTAMP** sample data is here:

```
    2013-08-02 00:15:00
    2013-08-03 00:30:00
    2013-08-04 00:45:00
    2013-08-05 08:45:00
    2013-08-06 08:45:01
    2013-08-08 08:45:02
```

In the above data, I have to change the **Date** to:

```
    2017-06-02 00:15:00
    2017-06-03 00:30:00
    2017-06-04 00:45:00
    2017-06-05 08:45:00
    2017-06-06 08:45:01
    2017-06-08 08:45:02
```

**So, How can I write an Expression in the Derived Column to change the Date from last six days? Without Changing the 'TimeReading' that is side to the Date.**

That means the **Date** should change and pop up from previous 6 days and **TimeReading next to the Date** should be same as previous data.

**What I did:**

In the Expression, if I give **GETDATE()** output is populating with today's date and the **TimeReading** is populating with 00:00:00.

If I give GETDATE()-1, output is populating with the previous date and **TimeReading**  is  populating with 00:00:00,

But I need to get the continuous date from the last **six days** with the same **TimeReading**.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to look at is the DateAddFunction. I think you are asking to subtract 6 days from the date in **TimeReading** (not sure because your example shows 2 days or 1 day). But regardless, for 6 days:

```
DateAdd(Day,6,TimeReading)
```

Create a new field using DerivedColumn to contain this new value.

Comment: Thanks for reply Marc, I have to change six days from the data like 2013-08-02 to 2017-06-02, in the same way, all the dates.

Comment: I don't understand, how are 2013-08-02 and 2017-06-02 six days apart?

Comment: it's 1575 days difference between those two days.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to just change fields in records that have one of those 6 dates?

Comment: Yes, I have to change field  2013-08-02 00:15:00 to 2017-06-02 00:15:00
Date field should be changed and Timestamp field should be same.